# Que vous sussiez / sachiez

Tags: subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Dans une lettre à Mme de Grignan (16 juin 1677), Mme de Sévigné écrit :

> J’attends encore de vos nouvelles de Chalon et de Lyon. Je viens de
> recevoir le petit billet du grand M. des Issarts. Il vous a vue et
> regardée ; vous lui avez parlé, vous l’avez assuré que vous êtes
> mieux. Je voudrais **que vous sussiez** comme il me paraît heureux, et ce que je ne donnerais point déjà pour avoir cette joie.

Je ne comprends pas très bien le sens du subjonctif imparfait ici.

Serait-il possible de remplacer l'imparfait du subjonctif par le présent du subjonctif (*que vous sachiez*) dans la citation ci-dessus ?

Comment: Ah là là, le français avec ses conjugaisons qui peuvent sonner bien étrange hors contexte.

Comment: Oui, il m'est vraiment difficile de comprendre cette conjugaison !

Comment: • Le subjonctif imparfait devrait s’employer dans une proposition subordonnée, pour indiquer la simultanéité ou la postériorité d’une action par rapport à l’action de la principale, lorsque celle-ci est au passé. https://bescherelle.com/lemploi-du-subjonctif-imparfait

Comment: Aujourd'hui on dirait sachiez, oui.

Comment: @Lambie D'accord, mais pourquoi existe-t-il différents temps au subjonctif alors qu'un pourrait remplacer l'autre ? (ici, d'après l'exemple donné, le présent et l'imparfait)

Comment: Moi, je ne connais pas la raison de la disparition. Trop compliqué?

Comment: @Lambie Probablement oui, c'est un peu bizarre de prononcer ce qu'on veut à l'instant pour quelque chose du passé, les temps sont chamboulés.

Answer (score 5):

C'est la concordance des temps normale : la proposition principale est au passé, syntaxiquement parlant, donc la proposition subordonnée aussi.

*Voudrais* est un conditionnel présent. La forme verbale qui sert de conditionnel en français est construite comme un futur du passé, et peut avoir ce sens, même si le sens hypothétique (un conditionnel au sens propre) est le plus courant. Par exemple, dans

> Je savais qu'il **deviendrait** célèbre.

le verbe de la proposition principale « savais » est au passé, et l'action de la proposition subordonnée est dans le futur par rapport à celle de la proposition principale, donc le verbe de la subordonnée est au futur du passé, qui est le conditionnel présent : « deviendrait ».

Dans « je voudrais … », le mode conditionnel n'a ni le sens d'un futur du passé, ni celui d'une hypothèse, mais d'un amoindrissement : « je voudrais » est moins fort que « je veux », il est à peu près équivalent à « je souhaite ». Mais quel que soit le sens, le verbe est à un temps du passé, donc on utilise un temps du passé dans la subordonnée.

> Je veux que vous **sachiez** …   (présent / présent)
> Je voulais que vous **sussiez** …   (passé / passé)
> Je voudrais que vous **sussiez** …   (futur du passé / passé)

En français moderne, le subjonctif imparfait a presque complètement disparu : on ne l'utilise plus dans la langue courante, et plus beaucoup dans la langue soutenue. Il est donc parfaitement normal de dire et d'écrire

> Je voulais que vous sachiez …
> Je voudrais que vous sachiez …

Mais au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle, on utilisait le subjonctif imparfait normalement (au moins dans la langue soutenue).

<sub>P.S. pour comprendre « ses conjugaisons qui peuvent sonner bien étrange hors contexte » : *sussiez* est une forme quasiment disparue du verbe *savoir*, mais a la même prononciation que *suciez* du verbe *sucer*. Et *sucer* a en général un complément d'object direct, à l'exception notable de son sens sexuel.</sub>

Comment: Techniquement, il voudrait qu'on le sache, mais dans le passé. Donc en réalité on peut comprendre dans une forme moderne "j'aurais voulu que vous sachiez", non?